# Active record: filter on distinct value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several entries in a table in my RoR app:

```
{id: 1, item_id: a, ...}
{id: 2, item_id: a, ...}
{id: 3, item_id: a, ...}
{id: 4, item_id: b, ...}
{id: 5, item_id: b, ...}
{id: 6, item_id: c, ...}
{id: 7, item_id: d, ...}
{id: 8, item_id: d, ...}
```

I would like to create a query that filters on **distinct** item_id and returns the first matching entry, so that the result would be

```
{id: 1, item_id: a, ...}
{id: 4, item_id: b, ...}
{id: 6, item_id: c, ...}
{id: 7, item_id: d, ...}
```

When using

```
select(:item_id).distinct
```

I cannot access the other attributes of the entries. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009297/selecting-columns-with-distinct-in-postgresql

Comment: This does not solve my question. ``Item.select("DISTINCT(item_id), *")`` results in all values

Comment: On what basis do you want to select these items? Just the first occurring for each `item_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the lowest id for every item_id, you could use an aggregate query to retrieve these ids:

```
grouped_with_min_id = Model.group(:item_id).minimum(:id)
rows = Model.find(grouped_with_min_id.map(&:id))
```

This may not be the most efficient solution as it uses two queries. But other methods will probably require you to use `Model.find_by_sql` and write your own sql.

Disclaimer: I did not try that out.